# Can't send an HTTP POST request in Ionic 3 / Angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, post, ionic3, angular5

I'm trying to send a post request from my **Ionic 3 (Angular 5)** app to my REST api, but I'm getting **HTTP 404 (Not found)** or **HTTP 400 (Bad request)**.

When I send the post request using Postman it is successful. And also, my GET request in Ionic 3 app works successfully. You can see success request below, it hasn't an *Authorization*:

[image: POST request header]

[image: POST request body]

Here is my request method:

```
sendConfirmationCode() {
    let mybody = new FormData();
    mybody.append('msisdn', '1234567');

    let myheaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    this.http.post('http://mydomain/methodname', mybody, {headers: myheaders})
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }, error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    })
  }
```

*With headers* I get HTTP 404 (Not found) but *without* HTTP 400 (Bad request). So, I tried different body objects with and without using headers. Here is my usings instead of `FormData` body object:

```
let mybody= new HttpParams();
mybody.append('msisdn', '1234567');
-----
let mybody= new URLSearchParams()
mybody.append('msisdn', '1234567');
-----
//SubscriberDataInput is my class for to use as input body model of api's method
let mybody = new SubscriberDataInput();
mybody.msisdn = '1234567';
-----
let mybody = JSON.stringify({ "msisdn": "1234567" });
```

And tried these cases for sending header instead of above header:

```
let Options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};
-----
let headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

None of them works successfully. Can you please tell the right way?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but since you get a HTTP 404 (Not found) with your headers, the `http://mydomain/methodname/` exists, and is prepared to work with post data at that address, and does not need an element reference?

Comment: so you mentioned that Postman works for your case correct? can you show how you configure your request in postman? this issue is really that client formed request is not valid, but to understand what exactly - you need to share successful case (Postman)

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I added screenshots, you can see above.

Comment: One more q - are you using Angular 5's http module? correct? @angular/common/http?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes, HttpClient from '@angular/common/http'.

Comment: hmm I would suspect you are not setting Content Type correctly. in POST/PUT requests Content Type defines data you sent and I am not sure you are sending valid json. Can you try setting Content Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, OR keep using application/json but format your data to be valid json?

Comment: to make it valid json use normal quotes: {
 "msisdn": "1224232"
}

Comment: and as for the body - don't turn it to string, leave it as JSON

Comment: I know, I used both { "msisdn": "1224232" } and JSON.stringify({'msisdn' : '1224232'}) with and without application/x-www-form-urlencoded, still get Bad Request. FYI, x-www-form-urlencoded and form-data doesnt work also in Postman, only raw body works there.

Comment: Ok last attempt;) try: Content-Type: text/plain while using same parameters as in Postman. Text/plain is used for raw data.

Comment: Same result (also didn't work in Postman).. 
I think the reason is something blocks my POST request because it is an ajax request and want to reach another port of localhost. Going to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was my RESTful api prevents ajax post requests. This is a solution in Asp.Net WebApi 2 which related Cors:

Add a constant into `Startup` class of **Startup.cs** :

```
private const string DefaultCorsPolicyName = "localhost";
```

Add Cors into `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup` class:

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(DefaultCorsPolicyName, builder =>
        {        
              builder
              .AllowAnyOrigin() 
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
```

Enable Cors in `Configure` method of `Startup` class:

```
app.UseCors(DefaultCorsPolicyName); //Enable CORS!
```

Delete **first** custom header in web.config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```